# Podio and Mailchimp Integration

Tags: integration, mailchimp, podio, auto-responder

I have a few web forms on podio. Podio doesnt offer automatic emails to be sent to people they fill an webform on our website. We want to integrate it with mailchimp. Can some 1 help us to understand mailchimp for this purpose

Comment: Hey,
Please try MailChimp integration for Podio developed by Phases.
http://newslettersync.com

Comment: Here are a few extensions that allow you to integrate with MailChimp. **MailChimp Podio Integration** (free)
https://podio.com/extensions/20 **Podbox**
https://podio.com/extensions/41 **PieSync**
https://podio.com/extensions/33

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure what you are trying to do exactly, but i have done multiple projects on mailchip and podio using zapier. you can add contacts to your mail list on mailchimp from your podio account

Answer (score 0):

Use [Zapier](https://zapier.com/app/explore) to create automatic emails, when a Podio webform is submitted.  I recommend using gmail as the mailserver in Zapier, it works better than Zapiers own. You can also integrate your Mailchimp account with Podio using Zapier, and then use the automation tool build in Mailchimp. But that is not good if you want the system to send more than one automail to the same email address. But that depends on purpose of the webform.